# less -S server.log (unix)

Tags: shell, unix, less, command-line-arguments

For a better understanding I prefer to read the logs with no wrap lines.

In less I can get this with the -S option.

The problem is that I can not select and copy rows that go beyond the right side of the screen.

How can I do?

Thx

Comment: less don't know or care about any clipboard copying. Terminal emulator does. If you asked less to not feed data to terminal, terminal is unable to select them. Only way I see is setting very high line width in terminal, probably much higher than screen - but it could break other programs.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using less, you could use the less.sh from vim.

It is located in "VIM install dir"/macros/less.sh

To keep lines from wrapping add this to your ~/.vimrc or execute from the ':' prompt:

```
set nowrap
```

Make sure that vim is installed/compiled with access to the X-server and the X11 clipboard.
I am not at a Unix system right now, there might be some extra tweaking involved to copy lines to the X11 clipboard